# Maximum values of Gabor filter

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

before asking I want to say that I know what is Gabor filter and I used it couple of times.

But I got something I theoretically dont understand.
(for example - I got this python + openCV + numpy code)

```
 for filter in filters:
            filtered = cv.filter2D(img, cv.CV_8UC3, filter)
            filtered = np.reshape(filtered, img.shape)
            np.maximum(accumulator, filtered, accumulator)
```

"filters" - are bank of Gabor filters.

As I know "filtered" is result of convolution in the spatial domain.

np.maximum takes all the values of filtered and compers it with accumulator values and stores only the Max values in accumulator.

What I dont understand and my main question is "What does maximum values of convolution result with gabor filter mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximum values of convolution with Gabor filters mean that at the spatial point they appear, there is a pattern corresponding to the specific Gabor filter you used.
Gabor filters are a Gaussian kernel function modulated by a sinusoidal plane wave, so it means that the corresponding frequency associated with the Gabor filter is present at the specific location where it obtained maximum value.

Comment: Does this include the minimum too or only max values represent the corresponding to the specific gabor filter?

Comment: Generally speaking minimum values will correspond with the lack of frequency associated with the Gabor filter at the respective spatial point within an image.